# java documentation of several packages

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, java-package

I've been recently asked to create a full Java documentation of all our APIs.

well creating a documentation for single **project** is easy `(open project then  eclipse->project->Generate javadoc)`.however, I'm not quite sure how is it possible to create a documentation for all the **projects** so they will be able to point to eachother.

in short to break down my question:

1. while commenting a `packageONE.classA` from `project1` how am I able to point to `package2.classB` in `project2` (assuming `pakcageONE.classA` uses API of `project2` `packageTWO.classB` now I want to simply point to it while writing the documentation.)
2. how is it possible (or is it at all possible) to create `javadoc` for all the projects at once. so `index.html` will show a list of `projects` and upon click on a `project` it opens all the `packages/classes` of that project (if `javadoc` is used for one project `index.html` points to all `packages/classes` of that project)
3. when creating a javadoc even for one project all the native java classes come as full path (e.g. instead of `String` it shows `java.lang.String` without links to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) so is it possible to first show it as `String` (instead of `java.lang.String`) and also link it to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

I hope question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

1-2 : did you try to select all projects before generating javadoc ?

3 : try using option `-link` or `-noqualifier`

see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html) for more explanation about options